# Angular 2 - Countdown timer

Tags: angular, rxjs, countdown, countdowntimer

I am willing to do a countdown timer in Angular 2 that start from 60 (i.e 59, 58,57, etc...)

For that I have the following:

```
constructor(){
  Observable.timer(0,1000).subscribe(timer=>{
  this.counter = timer;
});
}
```

The above, ticks every second, which is fine; however, it goes in an ascending order to an unlimited number. 
I am not sure if there is a way to tweak it so I can have a countdown timer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, a basic example is to use the `take` operator

```
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `<h2>{{counter$ | async}}</h2>`
})
export class App {
   counter$: Observable<number>;
   count = 60;

   constructor() {
     this.counter$ = timer(0,1000).pipe(
       take(this.count),
       map(() => --this.count)
     );
   }
}
```

#### A better way is to create a counter directive!

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject, Observable, Subscription, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[counter]'
})
export class CounterDirective implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {

  private _counterSource$ = new Subject<any>();
  private _subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;

  @Input() counter: number;
  @Input() interval: number;
  @Output() value = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() {

    this._subscription = this._counterSource$.pipe(
      switchMap(({ interval, count }) =>
        timer(0, interval).pipe(
          take(count),
          tap(() => this.value.emit(--count))
        )
      )
    ).subscribe();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this._counterSource$.next({ count: this.counter, interval: this.interval });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
<ng-container [counter]="60" [interval]="1000" (value)="count = $event">
  <span> {{ count }} </span>
</ng-container>
```

Here is a live [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p9xny6)

Comment: Mutating external state from within a composed observable is rarely a good idea and here it's unnecessary. An alternative: `Observable.timer(0, 1000).map(value => 60 - value).takeWhile(value => value > 0)`

Comment: @cartant this isn't a state. it is just a countdown timer

Comment: how can i achieve this when the counter hits to 0 it will recount again to 10. i mean in my in display. i use to display the number 10 and will start the countdown to 9 ,8 ,7 ,6 ,5 ,4.. and so on until it hits 0. and when it hits to zero it will start the countdown again to 10.

Comment: @JydonMah there is a `repeat()` operator that can be used at the end of the chain

Comment: thanks for this man, i add it in the end of the code but it continue to negative value. can you provide working example for it? it seems im having trouble figuring out. by the way im just new in angular and typescript :)

Comment: @MurhafSousli Is there some built-in property or something alternative I could use to have minutes and seconds? like MM:SS countdown?

Comment: Can I achieve this without implement <h2>{{countDown | async}}</h2> in html?

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia you can make pipe that will transform seconds into minutes

Comment: How do check, if the counter has reached 0?

Comment: @Shrinivas Add operator to check the count `map(() => if (this.count === 0))`

Answer (score 2):

Import into Component:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/timer";
import "rxjs/add/operator/finally";
import "rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
```

Function CountDown:

```
countdown: number;
 startCountdownTimer() {
    const interval = 1000;
    const duration = 10 * 1000;
    const stream$ = Observable.timer(0, interval)
      .finally(() => console.log("All done!"))
      .takeUntil(Observable.timer(duration + interval))
      .map(value => duration - value * interval);
    stream$.subscribe(value => this.countdown = value);
  }
```

Html :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h2 class="panel-title">Countdown timer</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div>
      <label>value: </label> {{countdown}}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button (click)="startCountdownTimer()" class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to stop the timer?

Comment: @Asif by unsubscribeing "stream$" observable.