# Timer countdown Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timer, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown timer for my Ionic2 app, the thing is that I was using this method from now [`countdown timer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489685/4329781) but now I have to create the countdown like 30:00 min, what's the better way to do it? Time could change, and if I want to fire something when the countdown it's done I only have to be comparing the `time` if it's 0, right?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can 'listen' to the timer and trigger the action when the countdown is 0. And to display the timer, use a pipe.

**HTML**

```
{{counter | formatTime}}
```

**TypeScript**

```
  countDown:Subscription;
  counter = 1800;
  tick = 1000;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.countDown = timer(0, this.tick)
      .subscribe(() => --this.counter)
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.countDown=null;
  }
```

**Pipe**

```
//for MM:SS format
  transform(value: number): string {
    const minutes: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
    return ('00' + minutes).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + Math.floor(value - minutes * 60)).slice(-2);
  }
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3fdr3k)**

```
//for HH:MM:SS format

transform(value: number): string {
    const hours: number = Math.floor(value / 3600);
    const minutes: number = Math.floor((value % 3600) / 60);
    return ('00' + hours).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + minutes).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + Math.floor(value - minutes * 60)).slice(-2);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsbdpt)

---

If you wish to use a service:

**Service**

```
 ...
  getCounter(tick) {
    return timer(0, tick) 
  }
 ...
```

**Component**

```
  countDown;
  counter=1800 ;
  tick=1000;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.countDown = this.myService.getCounter(this.tick).subscribe(() => this.counter--);

  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.countDown=null;
  }
```

**Pipe**

```
  ...  
  transform(value: number): string {
    //MM:SS format
    const minutes: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
    return ('00' + minutes).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + Math.floor(value - minutes * 60)).slice(-2);

    // for HH:MM:SS
    //const hours: number = Math.floor(value / 3600);
    //const minutes: number = Math.floor((value % 3600) / 60);
    //return ('00' + hours).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + minutes).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + Math.floor(value - minutes * 60)).slice(-2);

  }
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqkmsw)

Comment: That's the same code of the answer I linked, right? what if I want 30:00 with this I can't do it

Comment: Plus I can put it on a service and then synchronize it to my page?

Comment: If you put it in the service, subscribe to this

Comment: how to 30:00 ? on timer?

Comment: but with this I can see for example going from 30:00 to 29:59 29:58 ...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154877/discussion-between-stuart2041-and-vega).

Comment: if I get the value from api I got 16:28.564000000000078 why?

Comment: nono, my api value is something like this : remainingTime:1170.501

Comment: cna you join chat one second please?

Comment: but I'm getting this : Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '1244.533' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'  if I do something like this.countDown = 1244.533

Comment: Yes but I mean, on my page I'd like to get for example 1244.533 without the --countDown etc because this is on my service...

Comment: Vega I've edited the question with an example pls help

Comment: I just explained it on chat wish u understand what I'm trying to explain to you

Comment: the thing is to have this :  this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
      .take(this.counter)
      .map(() => --this.counter)
      .do(() => console.log("call here whatever you need")) on service and you on page just have for example this.countDown = myService.getTime() and get time is updating on service Is that possible?

Comment: this is how I ended up doing that, perfect man you're good! Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Vega Thanks it was helpful, one question how do I stop the timer if it's 0? I mean I did if(this.count === 0) this.sub.unsiscribe() but on the screen is going negative

Comment: Is this helpful: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8z6vcu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts ?

Comment: Hello @Vega, since I do not have a counter on my app because it is taken syncroniced from services, can I trigger when countdown is 0? I mean, I'm not able to create a variable like "counter" because on my app I have 2 devices that they are syncronicing every X seconds and this counter would change, I can trigger that countDown is 0 or something to call a function? I can do it from .html?

Comment: Hi @Vega If I want to include hour HH too, how should I change it?

Comment: @pavilion, I think this should do the trick : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtij4v

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution! It was exactly the thing I was looking for. But can you remove the spare "}" in the post at the map function. It cost me a lot of time to figure out the mistake I made. @Vega

Comment: @Vega may there should be subscriptions for the timer? I think theres more control about that. If you want to change your example with subscriptions I can give you the code.

Comment: For the first solution I get: `Template parse errors:
The pipe 'formatTime' could not be found ("
  <div>
      <h1>Countdown timer</h1>
      <h2>{{[ERROR ->]countDown | async | formatTime}}</h2>
    </div>
    
"): ng:///AppModule/QuizPageLoop.html@61:12`

Comment: When I am importing: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'`. Error occur `Module '"../../../../../../Unnati/WorkSpace/knowledgeUp/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.ts(2305)` @Vega

Comment: Version: "rxjs": "~6.5.1", I tried to import it in another way `import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';`  then it thrwos error `Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.` @Vega

Comment: @UnnatiPatadia, remove Observable, just timer.

Comment: @UnnatiPatadia, I updated the post with latest rxjs version

Comment: Is it possible to modify this to allow multiple count downs in the same page?

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus, keep multiple timer properties and adjust the method for them to be decremented/incremented

Answer (score 2):

Try this for timer:

```
<h5><span id="time" class="text-primary">00:00</span></h5>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        var callDuration = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#time');
        this.startTimer(callDuration);
    }

    startTimer(display) {
        var timer = 1800;
        var minutes;
        var seconds;

        Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
            minutes = Math.floor(timer / 60);
            seconds = Math.floor(timer % 60);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            --timer;
            if (timer < 0) {
                 console.log('timer is ended');
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll test this answer, to check what is more efficient, thanks @Chandru, by the way if instead of "timer" I have an api call that returns this : remainingTime:1244.529 with your option is possible to do that?

Comment: Yeah it's possible using this code .. set the remainingTime:1244.529 instead of 'timer' then the timer start with 20.44

Comment: and if I have this on a service, it can update the view ? I mean the countdown is running but if I do an api call and returns a different remaingingTime I have to update it, it is possible?

Comment: if you want to help me with that problem come on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338921/upload-a-view-from-service-every-x-seconds-ionic2)

Comment: chandru with your answer I can have the observable stuff in the service, and from page get the value? I mean service have the observable and on page I have the "timer" (in your code)?

Comment: Excellent thanks after spending hours. Simple quick responsive

Comment: After time up, timer and observer is still running how can I unsubscribe that observer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
maxtime: any=30

  StartTimer(){
    this.timer = setTimeout(x => 
      {
          if(this.maxTime <= 0) { }
          this.maxTime -= 1;

          if(this.maxTime>0){
            this.hidevalue = false;
            this.StartTimer();
          }

          else{
              this.hidevalue = true;
          }

      }, 1000);


  }
```